# Are there official guidelines on 5e feat creation or modification?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, homebrew

The DMG has a wealth of information on creating or customising monsters, spells, magic items, races, classes, and backgrounds. It seems to have no information whatsoever about feats.

I've done some digging, but can't seem to find any real information about how to properly go about making homebrew feats for 5e.

I've read Mike Mearls' advice in the UA release of feats, and while it's useful information, it's all pretty broad advice, with none of the depth or mechanical insights of the DMG content.

Is there a source where I can find information like this?

Answer (score 5):

The UA release you mentioned is the only source of advice specifically for feat creation [from the 5e development team to date](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/dnd/ua-feats-v1.pdf).

Comment: Dang! I feel like it would be off-topic for this stack to ask if there are any unofficial guidelines on the same—is that accurate? I've searched for that too (well, for _any_ guidance, reeally) and found it... lacking. I specifically asked for official sources since that seemed more in keeping with the guidelines.

Comment: I'm afraid that might be too broad. For what it's worth, I see 5 steps to the process. 1 come up with an idea, 2 compare it to existing feats, 3 playtest, 4 playtest, 5 playtest some more. If, after that, it's worth taking for some characters but not every character, you're good to go.

Comment: @DerekStucki Playtesting is overrated. You can ask 100 casual gamers to use a feat for 5 levels each, and still know less about its true potential than a heavy optimizer would after reading its description.

Comment: That sounds like very poor playtesting if you only ask one type of player to participate.